# October cms not displaying the backend

Tags: laravel, octobercms

After reseeding the users table my backend page is blank. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: This is a very general debugging question which I don't think anyone would be able to help you on without more details.  Set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and make sure `display_errors` is set to `on` in your php.ini file.  If that doesn't help, step through the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For some reason the backend wasn't wasn't seeded. I did php artisan october:down then php artisan october:up and it reappeared.